# I'm getting infinite loop and array is not printing as well

Tags: while-loop, python-3.8, infinite

```
noOfStudent = int(input("Enter Number of Student : "))

while range(noOfStudent):
    subjectArray = []
    markArray = []
    studentName = input("Enter Student Name : ")
    noOfSubject = int(input("Eneter Number of Subjects : "))
    totalMark = 0

    while range(noOfSubject):
        subjectName = input("Enter Subject Name : ")
        subjectArray.append(subjectName)
        mark = int(input("Enter Mark :"))
        markArray.append(mark)
        break
    
    totalMark = totalMark + mark

    average = totalMark / noOfSubject
    print(studentName,subjectArray,markArray)
    subjectArray.reverse()
    markArray.reverse()
    print(studentName,subjectArray,markArray)
    subjectArray.clear()
    markArray.clear()
    print(studentName,subjectArray,markArray)
```

Array is taking entries of the data but studentName is running infinitely
other than that it is not printing the Average as well as marks
it just keep taking entries and nothing else

I want students name with their subjects and marks as well as total of their marks along with avg

Comment: instead of while loops using the range() you should use for loops. like `for _ in range(noOfStudents):`. you also have a `break` in your second while loop which I don't believe would be the proper as you would breaking the loop prematurely before you go though the number of subjects

Comment: To get the average you might also want to put the `totalMark = totalMark + mark` indented into the noOfSubject loop as it will currently only print out the sum of the last mark